# How can I add the ' character into a string representing the JSON for a WS call in PHP?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am an abslolute beginner in **PHP** and moreover in **Laravel** framework (I came from Java).

I am finding the following problem trying to perform a **Guzzle** call to a REST web service:

if I do it using mocked creadential data it works fine:

```
    $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
                'pswd'
            ]
        ]);

    $dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());

    \Log::info('response: '.(json_encode($dettagliLogin)));
```

But trying to do in this way

```
    $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                //'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
                //'pswd'
                $credentials['email'] . ','
                .$credentials['password']
            ]
        ]);

    $dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());

    \Log::info('response: '.(json_encode($dettagliLogin)));
```

it goes into error.

I think that maybe the problem could depend by the fact that the mocked credential contain the **'** before and after username and password fields:

```
'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
'pswd'
```

How can I insert it in my dynamic version of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform like this:

```
   $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                $credentials['email'],   // <=== don't concatinate the comma here
                $credentials['password']
            ]
        ]);
```

No, need to concatinate the array parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting your credentials into a string, when it expects an array. Try the following;

```
$response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
    [
        'auth' => [
            $credentials['email'],
            $credentials['password']
        ]
    ]);
```